# Настал сезон раздачи шляп!

Tags: обсуждение, новогодние-шляпы

Еще один год стремительно близится к концу, а это значит, что настало время повеселиться. Шляпы в студию! Вы правы – пришло время нашего ежегодного события, которое приносит радость всем и множит число почитателей шляп…

**Новогодние шляпы – праздник зимы!**

[image: Winter Bash 2016 header/logo image]

Начиная с сегодняшнего дня и до конца 8 января 2017 года, вы можете заработать (и надеть!) шляпы за различные достижения на сайтах сети Stack Exchange.

#### Стоп. Что, снова шляпы?

Для тех, кто незнаком с праздником зимы и обычаем раздачи шляп, [мы подготовили длинную историю этой традиции (надеемся, что просмотр доставит вам удовольствие)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDi_nj1-G6U).

Выполнив одно из [множества заданий](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) после входа на один из [сайтов–участников](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/), вы получите соответствующую шляпу. Затем, вы можете зайти в свою учетную запись на любом сайте и выбрать шляпу по вкусу. Для этого нужно щелкнуть курсором на шляпе, «надетой» на раздел знаков в вашем профиле, появится диалоговое окно:

[image: Bobble hat icon on top right of badges box]

[image: Hat Dashboard/List of Hats Earned]

После того как вы выберете шляпу, вы можете переместить ее и изменить ее размер, чтобы она хорошо «сидела» на вашем аватаре. Пример:

[image: Movement and rotation controls attached to hat]

Кроме просмотра всех ваших шляп в учетной записи вы можете видеть свой  рейтинг на [доске достижений Новогодних шляп](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network). И только время покажет, кто наденет шляпу победителя!

Как всегда, если вы ненавидите шляпы и всю эту историю с праздником, вы можете не принимать в ней участия и не видеть никаких шляп. Любой участник имеет возможность «отписаться» от события, щелкнув на снежинке в верхней панели, а затем на ссылку «Я ненавижу шляпы» внизу слева. Если ваше отношение к шляпам изменится, пока не кончился «сезон шляп», вы можете изменить эти настройки.

#### Что нового в этом году?

Как и в предыдущие годы, к данному сезону мы подготовили новые «модели» шляп. В течение следующих недель вы можете побороться в общей сложности за 28 головных уборов. Как обычно, есть и секретные шляпы, в механизме получения которых произошло несколько незначительных изменений:

- Секретная шляпа за правильно угаданную секретную шляпу больше не присуждается.
- В этом году нет раздачи секретных шляп за многократное обращение к сотрудникам Software Exchange в комментариях к вопросам и ответам. Виноваты  юристы: им не понравилась мысль о том, что наших сотрудников постоянно отвлекают, требуя шляп.

Шляпы – потрясающий и веселый способ завершения года. Для нас, это способ показать вам, что мы вас любим. Мы вкладываем всю душу в создание шляп, которые бы понравились всем вам. В завершении, мы хотели бы поблагодарить всех, имеющих отношение к этому проекту:

- Команду маркетингового дизайна – за отличный дизайн. Специальной благодарности заслуживают Kalina Moniquet и [Nohemi Olvera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5921168/nohemi-olvera) за прекрасные изображения шляп.
- Нашу команду по документированию процесса: [Kaitlin Pike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741738/kcpike) за создание видео, [David Fullerton](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146719/david-fullerton) за идею и [Talal Sarwani](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/306119/talal) за управление проектом.
- Наших шляпограммистов, [Sklivvz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7028/sklivvz) и [Oded](https://stackexchange.com/users/1190/oded) за реализацию всей технической части проекта.
- Менеджера шляпного проекта, [balpha](http://stackexchange.com/users/40051/balpha), за отвагу и чуткое руководство на протяжении всего года.
- А также всех, кто предлагал свои идеи – за условия получения шляп, эскизы и помощь проекту.

**А теперь идите и соберите все шляпы!**

<sub>Свободный перевод публикации в блоге «[It's Hat Season...Announcing Winter Bash 2016](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/Its-Hat-Season-Announcing-Winter-Bash-2016/)».</sub>

Comment: Объединил метки в новую.

Comment: "шляпо-ботчиков" — ещё "шляпограммисты" приходят на ум. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin  Спасибо, поправил «шляпограммистов».

Comment: А шапки начисляют заранее :) `Bûche de Noël - спросите, ответьте или проголосуйте 25го декабря` уже выдали, а число, даже по местному времени, еще 24.

Comment: Шляпы? Это что, team fortes 2?

Comment: @Opossum К сожалению, не понял вашего вопроса. Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Visman шляпы, которые зависят от числа месяца,присуждаются за соответствующее действие когда где-то(не в Вашей timezone) уже наступило это число. например когда в Новой Зеландии 25 число, у нас еще 24. [Подобный вопрос на META](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288735/307712).

Comment: Шляпа, между прочим, на жаргоне означает означает одно из двух. Может как-то по другому назвать. Шапка например?

Comment: @Sergey У меня нет совершенно ни одной плохой ассоциации со словом «Шляпа» (я не знаю, про какой именно жаргон вы говорите). Подскажите, есть ли у вас другие варианты?