# Традиции Stack Overflow на русском. Празднование первого апреля

Tags: обсуждение

Мы как-то уже говорили о том, что по мере роста любого достаточно большого сообщества в нём неизбежно складываются свои традиции.

Я как человек новый, ещё даже полного года не прошло, но уже успел поучаствовать в [новогоднем конкурсе шляп](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4235/213987), а вот принято ли как-то праздновать первое апреля -- не знаю.

А задумался я об этом когда читал [вопрос "Являются ли HTML и CSS языками программирования? [дубликат]"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621396/213987): после того как в вопросе появилось уточнение "К примеру, на HTML+CSS возможна даже реализация [Правила 110](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_110)" я не удержался и съязвил в духе

> В майнкрафте создали даже вычислительную машину. Значит ли это, что
>   майнкрафт является тьюринг-полным и языком программирования?

В принципе, да -- я мог бы и задать такой вопрос на ru-so, только я думаю, что он будет закрыт и заминусован в течение пяти минут ;)

[image: компьютер в minecraft]

А с другой стороны: что мешает каждому придумать хороший смешной вопрос к первому апреля и запостить его, когда настанет дата?

Я видел на многих новостных сайтах среди фейковых первоапрельских новостей прячут настоящую -- просто она выглядит неправдоподобной и её ещё нужно суметь угадать!

Не знаю, получится ли такое провернуть, но до первого апреля ещё далеко, время есть подумать.

Comment: Не помню, чтобы 1 апреля как-то выделялся тут. А идея интересная. Делаем фейковые вопросы и ответы, а потом целый год выявляем дураков, купившихся на них =).

Comment: @avp и откатываем фейковую репу взад.

Comment: @avp, вроде раньше даже метка была?

Comment: @Qwertiy, может и была. Я не помню.

Comment: Ох. Представьте есть люди у которых спина на первое апреля не белая. И таких много. Заходишь такой на so, видишь смешнявки и начинаешь спамить тревогами. В любом случае даже для шляп есть кнопка "ненавижу шляпы". А первое апреля как-то выделяют в разы меньше людей

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, шляпы длятся месяц, а 1 апреля - 1 день ;) А ещё можно завести метку, которую можно будет кинуть в игнорируемое - вот и замена кнопочке.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я-то переживу, а случайный юзер зашедший сюда 1 апреля?

Comment: Как на счёт закрытия SO? Будет шок, трепет, интернеты взволнуются, акции рухнут, инвесторы отвернутся... Идею доработать можно.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос про Minecraft: redstone-схемотехника - обладает тьюринг полнотой.

Comment: Мне очень нравится один первоапрельский вопрос с en.SO, он долгое время был единственным у меня в "избранном": [Why is this program erroneously rejected by three C++ compilers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508110/why-is-this-program-erroneously-rejected-by-three-c-compilers) Онтопик, и хотя очевидная шутка, ответ действительно интересен.

Comment: @D-side Бесподобный вопрос! Кажется, его ждёт судьба Залго. )) Я думаю, нужно перевести такой шикарный вопрос и приводить на него ссылку тем, кто вопросы пишет с картинками.

Answer (score 24):

Когда-то при обсуждении метки для юнит-тестов предлагали вариант "модульные-испытания". Если бы в прошлом веке СССР выиграл технологическую гонку, то:

- В информационных технологиях преобладала бы русскоязычная терминология: испытания, а не тесты.
- Популярные языки программирования назывались бы иначе.
- Иначе назывались бы профессии. Не сеньор фронтенд-разработчик, а, например, разработчик пользовательского ПО первого разряда.
- Дальше можно фантазировать.

Можно на день поменять содержимое сайта: тексты, популярные метки и тому подобное.

В частности:

1. Поменять строки на сайте. Понадобится отдельная языковая база в Transifex, которую мы будем пере-переводить. Перед первым апреля нужно будет развернуть строки из неё, потом вернуть обратно.
2. Синонимизировать и объединить метки популярных языков к новым, через день вернуть обратно. (Сначала потренируемся на кошках).
3. Переименовать опытных участников в известных деятелей российской и советской науки. Где и когда ещё можно будет получить ответ от Ляпунова или Софьи Ковалевской? Разумеется, это дело добровольное.
4. Делать редирект на su.stackoverflow.com или даже stackoverflow.su.

Comment: Вроде нечто подобное было/есть на ВК.

Comment: @alexolut да, там есть советский язык. Но у нас будет интереснее, потому что мы не соцсеть, а специализированный сайт.

Comment: Сложность в том, что такую замену надо на уровне движка сделать и кратковременно. Хотя можно открыть `su.stackoverflow.com` (наполнить строки transifex'а) и форвардить на него первого числа :)

Comment: Переименовать, к сожалению, придётся аж на месяц. Просто на день нельзя.

Comment: @D-side на самом деле можно.....но.....переименовать обратно досрочно могут модераторы. И вряд ли они согласятся откатить имена вручника) .....но раз Nick предлагает.... xD

Comment: @D-side да, мы пооткатываем вручную ради такого дела. По крайней мере я согласен, остальные модераторы наверняка тоже подтянутся.

Comment: @alexolut отличная идея с доменом su! Можно даже позариться на stackoverflow.su, если выделят бюджет ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin первого уровня su вроде каких-то нереальных денег стоит. По идее он должен быть закрыт для расширений.

Comment: @alexolut 590 рублей в год, если я правильно понял https://www.nic.ru/dns/domain/su.html

Comment: @alexolut кстати, домен в любом случае стоит занять, чтобы не допустить киберсквоттинга. )

Answer (score 6):

Думаю да, стоит что-то придумать на 1 апреля. Но не совсем уж фейк, а что-то поинтереснее. Насколько я помню, раньше даже метка была под это дело, которую потом выпилили (хотя могу путать с SO).

А по поводу майнкрафта, на codegolf'е он [признан](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7377/programming-in-minecraft-redstone-how-to-measure-program-size) языком программирования.

Answer (score 6):

Предлагаю сделать **особую** метку `С 1 апреля!`.
Вопросы с такой меткой можно писать заранее, но они появятся в общем списке только 1 апреля.
При чтении вопроса метку не видно, но если вопрос минусуют, появляется надпись «Первое апреля — никому не веря!» и минусовать не дает. При повторной попытке вопрос можно заминусовать, если шутка неудачная.
Комментаторов и отвечающих предлагаю не предупреждать, если они сами не  догадались.

После 1 апреля метка становится видимой, а в вопрос большими буквами добавляется примечание, что это 1-апрельская шутка.
Первое апреля наступает по локальному времени, то есть жители восточной Сибири начинают шутить первыми.

Если эта идея интересна, надо придумать, что делать со старыми 1-апрельскими шутками на следующий год.

**UPD:**
На сайте [Mi yodea](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) (про иудаизм) существует тег `purim-torah-in-jest`, который используется во время праздника [Пурим](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC) и за какое-то время до него. С этим тегом публикуются шуточные вопросы, которые выглядят серьезными, с такими же ответами. [Purim Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) — это древняя пуримская традиция. Пример вопроса: [может ли еврей-джедай использовать Силу в Субботу](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69219/using-the-force-on-shabbat)?
Правила объясняются [на мете](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated). В частности, пользователи, кроме тега, должны сами вставлять стандартный код с предупреждением, что это шутка. Насколько я понимаю после окончания праздника Пурим вопросы должны закрываться вручную. Но, поскольку это должны делать пользователи, а не сайт, сейчас есть открытые вопросы с прошлогоднего Пурима.

В общем, потребность в такой функциональности есть, но реализации нет.

Comment: надо придумать что делать, если будут плюсовать, отвечать и отвечающим будут ставить плюсы :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я не думаю, что так можно набрать серьезную репутацию, так что пусть шутят и набирают. А кто сильно много наберет на этой метке, тому знак специальный выдать — 'Шутник', или 'Почетный первоапрелец', или еще как.

Comment: Такую функциональность без разработчиков сайта не сделать - раз. Объём доработок очень большой... не шляпы, но много - два. Даже если и согласятся, то не факт, что в этом году успеем -- это три. И четыре: вряд ли вообще такой сценарий получит зелёный свет. ;)

Answer (score 5):

вращать страницу сайта со скорость 1-5градуса в минуту, через 10 мин народ шеи посворачивает и будет очень озадачен! По F5 страничку можно снова вращать, но в другую сторону.

Интересно, что читающий скорее всего это не заметит, пока кто-то из-за его спины не притормозит заглядывая ему через плечи.

Answer (score 0):

Можно подменить ссылки в (новых и старых) вопросах, ответах и (новых) комментариях. Это удобно, потому что когда вы отвечаете новичкам, то ссылки можно оставить правильными, а когда вы знаете, что участник здесь давно и может оценить шутку, спокойно заменяйте. Например,

> посмотрите в [документации с++](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=34975233#34975233)

Comment: Вообще, неисчепаемые возможности для шуток у Николаса, скажем на некоторых сайтах видел как сайт вверх тормашками отображался. Или в дизайне некоторые элементы менялись. Но да, вопрос мой именно в том, чтобы самим посильный вклад внести, а не пассивно смотреть на то, что подготовила администрация.

Answer (score -2):

Если в начале текста вопроса будет явно (большими буквами, так сказать) сказано, что это ненастоящий вопрос (можно ещё и специальную метку какую-то добавлять, да), а второго апреля все эти вопросы будут удалены, то я не против.

Чтобы люди, которые не принимают участия во всех этих праздниках, не страдали, а также чтобы 10 октября в поисках информации не натыкаться на подобные вопросы.

Удаление вопросов, я так понимаю, заодно справится и с "и откатываем фейковую репу взад".

Comment: Шутка должна быть неожиданной, а иначе это плохая шутка. Обсуждение именно о том, что бы сделать такого неожиданного, подходящего, но при этом безобидного.

Comment: @D-side так вроде уже давно выяснили, что SO - это не форум и не место для общения не по теме. Речь про вопросы и ответы, составляющие базу знаний. Если это всё будет происходить, например, в общем чате - проблем не вижу.

Comment: Вопрос не требует скатываться к форумным нормам и к обсуждениям не по теме. Из него это никак не следует.

Comment: @D-side однако же в вопросе есть "я мог бы и задать такой вопрос на ru-so, только я думаю, что он будет закрыт и заминусован в течение пяти минут", а в комментариях - "Делаем фейковые вопросы и ответы, а потом целый год выявляем дураков, купившихся на них". Поэтому у меня создалось впечатление, что речь про вопросы, которые будут расценены как неприемлемые в другие дни.

Comment: "мог бы", но считает, что не может придумать достаточно хороший вопрос, удовлетворяющий требованиям качества сообщества и просит у сообщества поддержки в этом. В комментариях предлагают какой-то трэш/угар, серьёзные предложения скорее пошли бы в ответ. А то, что предложили вы, на мой взгляд даже хуже, чем вообще игнорировать 1 апреля. Отсюда мой минус, я с вашим предложением не согласен.

Answer (score -3):

Я за: несправедливо так, НГ есть, 1 апреля нет. Плюс одна идея в копилку: `lua` - язык программирования, LUA - последний универсальный общий предок.

Comment: Не понял шутку про общего предка.  Last U.. Ancestor?

Comment: @NickVolynkin last universal ancestor

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю, в чём шутка. )

Answer (score -5):

Предлагаю никак не праздновать Первое апреля или "День дурака" вовсе.

Comment: Что нам для этого нужно делать? С чего начнём?

Comment: @vp_arth не заходить на сайт в оный день, например.